# Large dataset crashes my browser

Tags: d3.js, crossfilter

I am loading a dataset of ~ 80,000 rows into a time series chart object I've created, and it's crashing my browser.

I don't think it should be a problem for d3, as [this Crossfilter example](http://square.github.com/crossfilter/) demonstrates with a [dataset](http://square.github.com/crossfilter/flights-3m.json) of several hundred thousand rows. (Although, the data are being aggregated, whereas I am graphing each point).

I am not sure how to debug this. Chrome isn't giving me any useful messages and Google results are scarce. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

If you are loading huge remote data using chrome than this is known [issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=138506). Chrome crashes on receiving large datasets via xhr. To solve this problem you can either receive data by chunks or receive it over web sockets.

Answer (score 1):

It depends, if you are appending 80,000 elements to the DOM, thats huge and I'm not surprised if its crashing the browser. The Crossfilter example does indeed have several hundred thousand rows but performs minimal DOM manipulation due to the aggregation (as you mentioned). You might take a look at canvas instead.

Comment: What's the solution for time series data, then, a la [Google finance charts](https://www.google.com/finance?q=INDEXDJX%3A.DJI&ei=1jlaUcjcA6W30gGTNw)?

Comment: In fact it's not appending a new element for each observation, since I'm using a [simple time series chart](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955). Any idea?

Comment: Seeing your code would definitely help, but as a starting point, maybe try running your line generator function without any DOM manipulation. Simply pass in your data and see if it crashes. That would at least narrow it down.

Comment: This is something like 11,000 rows: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/samselikoff/rbxQq/5/). It works but it gets slow and if I turned it up I think it would crash.

Answer (score -1):

you can disable browser extensions, and try, if your results are in flash, or java, disable chrome java extension, if they are showing in pdf disable chrome pdf extension and let OS decide which program to use, it'll still show up in chrome but won't crash. chrome://plugins/
sometimes chrome has two extensions for one program disable one of them